# What is the difference between my two Shotwell options?

Tags: shotwell, snap-store

I'm setting up a new laptop, there are two options for Shotwell. One has the tagline "Organize your photos" and is installed. The other is tagged "Digital photo organizer".

[image: Screenshot showing Shotwell twice in the Software Store]

"Organize your photos" is v. 0.30.14 from  https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell and "Digital photo organizer" is v. 0.32.1 from https://github.com/ubuntu/shotwell/issues

Why would there be two, and is there a meaningful difference between these versions?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?